# How to identify duplicates along with special characters in Oracle

Tags: string, oracle

I have the Employer table which has two columns, Ecode and Ename.

```
ecode   empname    

E1  NIKHIL
E2  Nikhil.
E3  Nikhil??
E4  sunita..
E5  sunita..
E6  sunita
E7  Mangesh
E8  HIREN
E9  HIREN..
E10 HIREN??
E11 Viren
```

I need the output to include duplicate values of `Empname`,  ignoring special characters. `Nikhil`, `Nikhil.`, `Nikhil?` all should be part of my output.

Expected Output:-

```
ecode   ename
E1  NIKHIL
E2  Nikhil.
E3  Nikhil??
E4  sunita..
E5  sunita..
E6  sunita
E8  HIREN
E9  HIREN..
E10 HIREN??
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with test (ecode, empname) as
(
select 'E1'  ,'NIKHIL'    from dual union all
select 'E2'  ,'Nikhil.'   from dual union all
select 'E3'  ,'Nikhil??'  from dual union all
select 'E4'  ,'sunita..'  from dual union all
select 'E5'  ,'sunita..'  from dual union all
select 'E6'  ,'sunita'    from dual union all
select 'E7'  ,'Mangesh'   from dual union all
select 'E8'  ,'HIREN'     from dual union all
select 'E9'  ,'HIREN.'    from dual union all
select 'E10' ,'HIREN??'   from dual union all
select 'E11' ,'Viren'     from dual
)
select ecode, empname,
dense_rank() over (order by upper(regexp_replace(empname, '\W'))) grp
from
   (select t.*,
    count(*) over (partition by upper(regexp_replace(empname, '\W'))) cnt
    from test t
   )
where cnt > 1
order by upper(regexp_replace(empname, '\W')), empname;

ECO EMPNAME         GRP
--- -------- ----------
E8  HIREN             1
E9  HIREN.            1
E10 HIREN??           1
E1  NIKHIL            2
E2  Nikhil.           2
E3  Nikhil??          2
E6  sunita            3
E5  sunita..          3
E4  sunita..          3

9 rows selected.
```

Comment: Just needs an ORDER BY clause to be a perfect answer.

Comment: need criteria for order by clause.

Comment: @APC, I do not understand what you mean. You are did not use "partition by" clause with "large data set" or you want to suggest another solution? Or may be we should not work with "large data set" and window funtions was designed for "small data set"?

Comment: "count(*) over (partition by ...)" is used to counting group's counts to find duplicates. If you want to show groups (as you said group them together) you may use dense_rank as I set for your by editing my answer. But if you want to data be sorted you must specify ORDER BY criteria as I said before.

Comment: By grouping, I just meant that the duplicates should follow sequentially in the result set. The ORDER BY is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option: find duplicates on `EMPNAME` column by removing anything but letters (that's what `'[^[:alpha:]]'` does):

```
SQL> with test (ecode, empname) as
  2  (
  3  select 'E1'  ,'NIKHIL'    from dual union all
  4  select 'E2'  ,'Nikhil.'   from dual union all
  5  select 'E3'  ,'Nikhil??'  from dual union all
  6  select 'E4'  ,'sunita..'  from dual union all
  7  select 'E5'  ,'sunita..'  from dual union all
  8  select 'E6'  ,'sunita'    from dual union all
  9  select 'E7'  ,'Mangesh'   from dual union all
 10  select 'E8'  ,'HIREN'     from dual union all
 11  select 'E9'  ,'HIREN.'    from dual union all
 12  select 'E10' ,'HIREN??'   from dual union all
 13  select 'E11' ,'Viren'     from dual
 14  ),
 15  inter as
 16    (select ecode, empname, upper(regexp_replace(empname, '[^[:alpha:]]', '')) rc
 17     from test
 18    )
 19  select ecode, empname
 20  from inter
 21  where rc in (select rc from inter
 22               group by rc
 23               having count(*) > 1
 24              )
 25  order by to_number(regexp_substr(ecode, '\d+$'));

ECO EMPNAME
--- --------
E1  NIKHIL
E2  Nikhil.
E3  Nikhil??
E4  sunita..
E5  sunita..
E6  sunita
E8  HIREN
E9  HIREN.
E10 HIREN??

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Clever use of regex to order the result set but on a large data set the inefficiency of calling `regexp_replace()` three times would start to bite.

Comment: Yes, it would, @APC. So I deleted some, to make it prettier.